# How to give row number for consecutive combination and duplicate it for duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created simple table to illustrate my problem:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
          (
              id int,
              Type VARCHAR(10),
              SectionId int
          )

Insert into @Test
SELECT 1,'RED', 100
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'RED', 100
UNION ALL  SELECT 3, 'BLUE', 100
UNION ALL SELECT  4, 'RED', 200
UNION ALL SELECT  5, 'BLUE', 200
UNION ALL SELECT  6, 'RED', 300
UNION ALL SELECT  7, 'BLUE', 300
UNION ALL SELECT  8, 'BLUE', 300
```

So I want to give row number to each row but repeat it when **Type** and **SectionId** is the same:

```
id, Type, SectionId, RowNumber
1, 'RED', 100        1
2, 'RED', 100        1
3, 'BLUE',100        2
4, 'RED', 200        1
5, 'BLUE',200        2
6, 'RED', 300        1
7, 'BLUE',300        2
8, 'BLUE',300        2
```

if I try `ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition by SectionId, Type Order by id)` I will get result like that:

```
id, Type, SectionId, RowNumber
1, 'RED', 100        1
2, 'RED', 100        2
3, 'BLUE',100        1
4, 'RED', 200        1
5, 'BLUE',200        1
6, 'RED', 300        1
7, 'BLUE',300        1
8, 'BLUE',300        2
```

Please tell me if there are any way to do that.

**Database that I used is Microsoft SQL Server (ver. 14.00.3045)**

Comment: Please also post your query

Comment: @DaleBurrell can't be MySQL because MySQL does not have table data type.

Comment: Which database and *which version*?  MySQL supports ROW_NUMBER() only in the latest version, 8.0

Comment: Sorry that I didn't specify what DB I use

Comment: What's the logic behind those values? Why should `(4,'RED',200)` return 1 when both the previous row returned 2 and the previous `RED` values returned 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`:

```
SELECT id, type, sectionid
     , dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY sectionid ORDER BY type DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM test
ORDER BY id;
```

```
id          Type        SectionId   RowNumber 
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           RED         100         1         
2           RED         100         1         
3           BLUE        100         2         
4           RED         200         1         
5           BLUE        200         2         
6           RED         300         1         
7           BLUE        300         2         
8           BLUE        300         2
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=4a35333b7735e62110b7b8a9ac2664f3)

Comment: Good job realizing that the grouping isn't based on duplicate values

Comment: This is a good solution

Answer (score 2):

Use [dense_rank()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which will return the rank of each row within a result set partition

```
  WITH cte AS (
        SELECT id, Type, SectionId,
           dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY SectionId ORDER BY Type DESC) rn
        FROM  yourtable
    )

    SELECT
        *
    FROM cte
```

Comment: Better but still doesn't give the results OP wanted (The red and blue row numbers are reversed). See my answer for one that does.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below - you need to add Type with SectionId to partition by clause

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition by Type,SectionId Order by id) as rn
from tablename
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the OP's desired result.